# VMware in SecureBoot Linux problem

Tags: 16.04, vmware, secure-boot

My problem is: when I install `Vmware` on `Linux Ubuntu 16.04` shows this problem `Could not open /dev/vmmon Please make sure that the kernel module vmmon' is loaded.`

I put this `sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` in the terminal, and nothing works.

I also saw these two answers: [answer1](https://gorka.eguileor.com/vbox-vmware-in-secureboot-linux-2016-update/#tc-comment-title) [answer2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707281/vmware-workstation-12-vmmon-not-found-or-not-loaded) (I thought that they would be solutions.)

The problem is that I don't have much knowledge in Linux (basics only) and because of that I am not understanding some of the following things:

1. How do I know if I have a `X509` key?
2. What is `MOK` and `Akrog` how it works and what is the purpose?
3. When I use this `/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vmmon)` tells me unknown directory

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Did you find any answer to your problem?