# Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel, vmware

I got following error when I open the virtual machine in vmware workstation:

```
Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory. Please make sure  that the kernel module `vmmon' is loaded.
```

Then I clicked ok, and another error like bellow reported and vmware workstation quit launching my virtual machine for me:

```
Failed to initialize monitor device.
```

Maybe this has something to do with my system updating.

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707281/vmware-workstation-12-vmmon-not-found-or-not-loaded) post, and I did like they said:

```
 1. openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform
    DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=VMware/"
 2. openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform
    DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=VMware/"
 3. sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256
    ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vmnet)
 4. sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
```

But when I exec ***sudo mokutil --import MOK.der***, I got an error:

```
EFI variables are not supported on this system
```

and when I exec ***sudo modprobe vmmon***, I got an error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vmmon': Exec format error
```

and when I exec ***sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all***

```
[AppLoader] GLib does not have GSettings support.
Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Blocking file system                                                done
Using kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only/common/hashFunc.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only/common/task.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only/vmcore/moduleloop.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only/bootstrap/bootstrap.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoader.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoaderVmmon.o
/tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:985:1: warning: always_inline function might not be inlinable [-Wattributes]
 LinuxDriverSyncReadTSCs(uint64 *delta) // OUT: TSC max - TSC min
 ^
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only/vmmon.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only/vmmon.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only/vmmon.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only'
cp -f vmmon.ko ./../vmmon.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmmon-only'
Using kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/hub.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/userif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/netif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/bridge.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/procfs.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/smac.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/vnetEvent.o
In file included from include/linux/pci.h:35:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/netif.c:43:
include/linux/pci_ids.h:2253:0: warning: "PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad
 ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/netif.c:42:
/tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:56:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE                    0x15AD
 ^
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.o
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/bridge.c:53:
/tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:56:0: warning: "PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE                    0x15AD
 ^
In file included from include/linux/pci.h:35:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/bridge.c:52:
include/linux/pci_ids.h:2253:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad
 ^
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/vmnet.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/vmnet.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only'
cp -f vmnet.ko ./../vmnet.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-iwyoC2/vmnet-only'
Starting VMware services:
   Virtual machine monitor                                            failed
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Blocking file system                                                done
   Virtual ethernet                                                   failed
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
Unable to start services
```

What does this mean? How to solve it? I have tried so many ways but all of them are invalid, please help.

**BTW: my computer secure boot is disabled**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same issues. The only thing which helped me was going back to the previous kernel version. Did that by following the instructions here: http://karlcode.owtelse.com/blog/2017/03/13/reverting-to-a-previous-kernel/